# Know IP Address of USB tethering interface in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking, windows-phone-7.1, ip-address

Is it possible to know the IPAddress of Windows Phone [Mango] devices when connected to PC through USB tethering.?

I am asking this because when i connect my phone to pc, using sockets it can connect to ANY Ipaddress. In other words, the `SocketError` enumeration always return me `Success`. which is quite strange.

If someone help me clarifying this issue.
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

The phone itself can be accessed via the loopback interface (aka 127.0.0.1) - you can see that if you try to analyze the network traffic for a debug session. The level of access, however, is limited to the extent of the debugger integration.

Answer (score 0):

While the phone is connected it gets the IP address 192.168.55.101. The network interface of the computer (e.g. to connect to it from the phone) has the address 192.168.55.100.

Comment: this does not happens in Windows Phone 7 and above

Comment: I actually tried that. Works for me, at least as long as the app is run from Visual Studio.
Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9139738/581887